# Google Code vs. Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting, google-code, web-hosting

I am confused.  I thought these were both hosting solutions that Google sells or makes free.  What is the difference between the two?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) is a SourceForge-style hosting solution for open source projects: you can host your code in a supplied Subversion or Mercurial repository and document your project in a wiki. You cannot run code on Google Code, only upload your source code to share with others. It's free.

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) is a general cloud application host. You can host web sites written in Python or Java, actually running code on Google's servers, with cost proportional to usage (it's free up to some amount).

Comment: GAE is free up to a certain point - 500 MB storage and 5 million views a month.

Comment: Thanks. Reading the links it looks like you can run Java (+ Scala + JRuby etc.) code on GAE too - so I'm well out of date.